# Find all Sylow 3-subgroups of $S_3\times S_3$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Find all Sylow 3-subgroups of $S_3\times S_3$?

This is what I already found:
Since $o(S_3\times S_3)=36=2^2 3^2$ Sylow- $3$ subgroups have order $9$. If $n_3$ is the no. of Sylow- $3$ subgroups, Then $n_3|4$ and $3|(n_3 - 1)$. Hence $n_3$ should be $1$ or $4$. Now how can I find at least one subgroup of order $9$?

Comment: Do you see any copies of $\mathbb{Z}/3$ in $S_3$?

Comment: No idea, But I think there are no copies.

Comment: Oops Im sory I got it, $Z/3$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_3$. Am I correct?

Comment: Indeed you are. Note that @rogerl asked about it for a very specific reason.

Comment: Ok, that subgroup is ${I, (123), (132)}$. Then $<(I, (123)),((123),I)>$ must be a subgroup of $S_3\times S_3$ which is of order 9. Correct?

Comment: Well, if by $(I,(123))$ you mean the subgroup generated by $(123)$, then yes.

Comment: Ok, now given any $\sigma\in S_3$ $\sigma(123)\sigma^{-1}$ is either $I, (123)$ or $(132)$. Is this argument enough to say that the subgroup $<(I,(123)),((123),I)>$ is normal?

Comment: Yes, it is. Or if you know the general statement that if $A$ is normal in $G$ and $B$ is normal in $H$ then $A\times B$ is normal in $G\times H$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint $A_3 \times A_3 = (S_3 \times S_3)'$ is a normal subgroup of order $9$.

Answer (score 0):

There's a normal one (as pointed out by Nicky Hekster).

Once that happens we know that there's only $1$, because they're all conjugate,  by Sylow.

It's (isomorphic to) $\Bbb Z_3^2.$

Answer (score 0):

The elements of order $3$ in $S_3\times S_3$ are:
\begin{alignat}{1}
&((123),()) \\
&((132),()) \\
&((),(123)) \\
&((),(132)) \\
&((123),(123)) \\
&((123),(132)) \\
&((132),(123)) \\
&((132),(132)) \\
\end{alignat}
Jointly with $()$, they form a closed subset of $S_3\times S_3$, which is then a subgroup of order $9$, say $P_9$, clearly isomorphic to $C_3^2$. As there isn't any other element of order $3$, $P_9$ is unique.